# group subplots in jupyter from list of plots generated from for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

I"m attempting to capture my plots in a list.  From the list of plot objects, I would like to create 3 or 4 plots side by side on my jupyter output.  I can't figure out how to display my plot objects from my list.  I can get them in the list, but can't display them properly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility

list_of_plots = []
for i in range(0,5):
    
    plt.rcdefaults()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Example data
    people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
    performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
    error = np.random.rand(len(people))

    ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
    ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
    ax.set_yticklabels(people)
    ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
    ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
    ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

    list_of_plots.append(ax)
```

Comment: matplotlib already has subplot functionality. if you put the call to `plt.subpots()` before the loop you'd be able to use it. examples and details here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: I review the link, but I"m still stumped.  Will you provide an example for me using the reprex provided?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the question but if it helps

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

# Fixing random state for reproducibility

list_of_plots = []

plt.rcdefaults()

for i in range(0,5):
    
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 5, i+1)

    # Example data
    people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
    performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
    error = np.random.rand(len(people))

    ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
    if not i:
        ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
        ax.set_yticklabels(people)
        ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
    else:
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
    ax.set_title('How fast do you\nwant to go today?')

    list_of_plots.append(ax)
```

output :

[image: output]